# SPUserToken in Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Through C#, we use the following code to impersonate a user, as an alternative to `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`.

```
SPUserToken ut = web.EnsureUser("<userName").UserToken;
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl, ut))
{
 //logic goes here
}
```

How can we achieve such a thing in PowerShell? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is piece of code to use impersonation:

```
$user=$web.AllUsers.GetByID(1073741823)

$token = $user.UserToken;

$impWebObj= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $token);
```

Read complete code here: [Powershell and Sharepoint: Impersonation](http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.in/2011/04/powershell-and-sharepoint-impersonation.html)